# Tor Hidden Service with python on Windows 7

Tags: python, service, hidden, tor

I would like to create on my Windows 7 a Hidden Service with Tor, but all of explanations are for linux or mac os.

Who can help me or discribe me the different step to build my Hiddent Service on Windows ?

The main goal of my project is to create a python script to install a Hidden Service on a Windows 7 (maybe Windows 10)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The configuration in your torrc is identical for Windows as it is in Linux.  Simply map the [HiddenServicePort](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en) to the port your Python application is listening on and set the `HiddenServiceDir` to some location to hold the keys.  What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Ok so I need to configure the torrc and then ?